# TypeError, having issues defining certain things

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, typeerror

Ok So, I'm making a simple game in python and pygame, where you're a spaceship and have to dodge meteors. But after adding in the meteor and writing the code to get it to spawn randomly and move down the screen. I had issues using the code tags as well, I'd do Ctrl + K and post my code inside the space provided and it gave me the code error. Sorry about that, here's my links (not the best way to do it I know, I couldn't get the code tags to work.)

**My Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\fredd_000\Desktop\Pygame_Script.py", line 127, in <module>
    game_loop()
  File "C:\Users\fredd_000\Desktop\Pygame_Script.py", line 98, in game_loop
    things(thing_startx, thing_starty, thing_width, thing_height, black)
  File "C:\Users\fredd_000\Desktop\Pygame_Script.py", line 28, in things
    pygame.draw.circle(gameDisplay, color,[thingx, thingy, thingw, thingh])
TypeError: function takes at least 4 arguments (3 given)
```

**My code where the error occurs:**

```
def things(thingx, thingy, thingw, thingh, color):
    pygame.draw.circle(gameDisplay, color,[thingx, thingy, thingw, thingh])
```

**Full code:**

```
import pygame
import time
import random

pygame.init()


display_width = 1200
display_height = 800

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('A Game By Freddie')

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
blue = (25,0,255)
red = (255,0,0)

car_width = 195
car_height = 1

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
gameExit = False
shipImg = pygame.image.load('ship.png')


def things(thingx, thingy, thingw, thingh, color):
    pygame.draw.circle(gameDisplay, color,[thingx, thingy, thingw, thingh])

def ship(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(shipImg, (x,y))

def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, red)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()



def message_display(text):
    largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',120)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text, largeText)
    TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/2))
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

    pygame.display.update()

    time.sleep(2)

    game_loop()



def crash():
    message_display('You Died')

def game_loop():

    x =  (display_width * 0.375)
    y = (display_height * 0.65)

    x_change = 0
    y_change = 0


    thing_startx = random.randrange(0, display_width)
    thing_starty = -600
    thing_speed = 7
    thing_width = 100
    thing_height = 100

    gameExit = False

    while not gameExit:


        gameDisplay.fill(blue)
        shipImg = pygame.image.load('ship.png')
        ship(x,y)
        pygame.display.update()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                gameExit = True
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    x_change = -5
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 5

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 0


        x += x_change



        things(thing_startx, thing_starty, thing_width, thing_height, black)
        thing_starty += thing_speed

        if x > display_width - car_width or x < 0:
            crash()

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    y_change = -5
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    y_change = 5

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    y_change = 0

        y += y_change

        if y > display_height - car_height or y < 0:
            crash()





            pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)


game_loop()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: `pygame.draw.circle(gameDisplay, color,[thingx, thingy, thingw, thingh])
` ** `TypeError: function takes at least 4 arguments (3 given) ` ** what do you understand from this? Hint: http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.circle

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that your using `pygame.draw.circle()` wrong. The syntax for using the function is: `pygame.draw.circle(screen, color, (x, y), diameter)`. As you can probably tell, the way you did it was `pygame.draw.circle(screen, color, [x, y, w, h])`. This is incorrect, a circle does not have a width and height. Change your code to: `pygame.draw.circle(gameDisplay, color, (thingx, thingy), thingw)`. `thingw` will be the diameter of your circle.

You should also change your function paramters to `def things(thingx, thingy, thingw, color)`.

If your still new to Pygame or confused on how to draw shapes to the screen, i highly suggest reading the [Pygame documentation on drawing](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html), as Idos linked to in the comments.